# update dataset command

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset and I'm adding new rows, and then I'm updating the database behind the dataset using the following command:

```
 DataSetReasons ds = new DataSetReasons();
      DataSetReasonsTableAdapters.Data_Tracker_RcodeTableAdapter dta = new DataSetReasonsTableAdapters.Data_Tracker_RcodeTableAdapter();

        DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable GRX =
        new DataSetReasons.Data_Tracker_RcodeDataTable();


        DataRow rowx = GRX.NewRow();
        rowx[0] = 111;
        rowx[1] = 28;
        rowx[2] = "C";
        rowx[3] = 12;
        rowx[4] = "C";
        rowx[5] = 16;
        rowx[6] = TextBox2.Text;

        GRX.Rows.Add(rowx); //<--- adding the row

        dta.Update(GRX); //<-- updating the DB
```

now everything works fine, except that I want to put the update command in a separate button. when I do so, the DB update are not happening.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was missing the "static" word before defining the data table.

Many thanks to whoever passed on this question.